# How to Zip an Excel File?

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to figure out how to zip an Excel .Xlsm file with no luck. The following code creates the zip file, but I can't figure out how to send the .xlsm file to it. Any help is appreciated!

```vb
Dim zipPath As String = RegScoringWorkbookName.Replace(".xlsm", ".zip") 'create zip file from .xlsm file
Try
    If File.Exists(zipPath) Then
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(zipPath, FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs,
                        FileIO.RecycleOption.DeletePermanently)
    End If
    Dim FilePath As String = RegScoringWorkbookName 'path of .xlsm file
    Using FileStream = New FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.CreateNew)
        Using archive = New ZipArchive(FileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, True)
            Dim zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(GetFileName(FilePath), CompressionLevel.Optimal)
            Using zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open()
                ' zipStream.WriteAsync()
                zipStream.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Comment: How is this specific to Excel files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just quote MSDN code here, since there is this exact example.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/system.io.compression.ziparchive

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim zipPath As String = "c:\users\exampleuser\end.zip"
    Dim extractPath As String = "c:\users\exampleuser\extract"
    Dim newFile As String = "c:\users\exampleuser\NewFile.txt"

    Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create) 'Changed this to create from MSDN
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(newFile, "NewEntry.txt", CompressionLevel.Fastest)
    End Using
End Sub

End Module
```

It should be pretty self explanatory. There is no need to use a filestream at this point, as there is a premade method to zip an existing file, `CreateEntryFromFile`.

Comment: This did the trick Jens. I searched and never came across this msdn example.